# r - subfolder csv merging R and indexing

Tags: r, csv

I'm really new to R and have to deal with the following problem

in a directory structured like that :

- dir

  - subD1

    - info.csv
    - main.csv
  - subD2

    - info.csv
    - main.csv

...

I would like to get a one row column called ID in the info.csv,then create a new column "info_id" in the main.csv applied to all the row.

Then merging the resulting frames.

Not recursively :

```
a <- read.csv("info.csv")
b <- read.csv("main.csv")
a <- rename.variable(a, "info", "info_id") 
df <- merge(b,a$info_id)
```

and for the recursive part I may use the following :

```
files <- list.files( 
 path = "/dir",
 pattern = "main",
 recursive = TRUE) #create a list of the file based on a regex

user.csv <- do.call(    
  rbind, lapply(
  files, function(x) read.csv(
  x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))) # import multiple csv and merge them
```

But I can't wrap all this in a nice function.

Thanks,